# Getting frame of child view controller with parent's coordinates

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a view controller which instantiates a child view controller, and I set its frame origin x to 50 from the parent's viewdidload and works fine, but when child viewcontroller viewdidload triggers I want to get the frame of the child view in reference to the parent view controller's view but get 0. I suppose is getting the frame in reference to the child view controller instead of the parent which is what I want to get.

Essentially I'm trying to implement a pan gesture to move the child around the parent and that's why i need its frame in the parent's geometry. Is it possible?

The end result is a table view at the back of the topview controller that is a table view like in facebook app.

Root

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboardAlpha" bundle:nil];
    self.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Prime"];

    _layerPosition1 = _topViewController.view.frame.origin.x;
}
- (void)setTopViewController:(UIViewController *)topViewController
{
    CGRect topViewFrame = _topViewController ? _topViewController.view.frame : self.view.bounds;
    topViewFrame.origin.x += 50;
    [_topViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_topViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [_topViewController removeFromParentViewController];

    _topViewController = topViewController;

    [self addChildViewController:self.topViewController];
    [self.topViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [_topViewController.view setAutoresizingMask:self.autoResizeToFillScreen];
    [_topViewController.view setFrame:topViewFrame];
    _topViewController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    _topViewController.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.layer.bounds].CGPath;

    [self.view addSubview:_topViewController.view];
}

- (NSUInteger)autoResizeToFillScreen
{
    return (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);
}
```

Child

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    SoulPrimeOmegaViewController *parent = (SoulPrimeOmegaViewController *)self.parentViewController;
    _layerPosition2 = parent.topViewController.view.frame.origin.x;
}
```

Comment: See the docs for `UIView convertRect:fromView:` and `UIView convertRect:toView:`.

Comment: Just edited the post to show the code, the problem is white the first layerposition has a 50 in x, the second one has 0. I need the reading from the first layerpostion accesible from the child view controller

Comment: Thanks but I couldnt make it work with your suggestion.